# How to invoke a specific instance of an activity from notification manager?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am able to direct user to an activity from Notification Manager by using intent:

```
       intent.setClass(mContext, ChatActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("UserId", user.getmPhoneNumber());
```

No problem in here..

But I'd like to direct the user to a specific instance of ChatActivity. I mean if the message comes from "user123", I need to open the chat screen of this user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onNewIntent() method solved my problem.

Overrided the onNewMethod() method in the activity and the magic happened onResume() method. Called getIntent() from here and changed/updated the info of the new user.

Comment: Hello Coldfish, please write up on how `onNewIntent` solved your issue and mark it as the answer for everyone to benefit.

Answer (score 1):

you are putting UserId in your intent, Check userId in your ChatACtivity and do whatever you want for that user

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating your `PendingIntent` you will include the Activity to open and from whom the message is from, as an extra. You have already done that. I can see that you are including `UserId`.

So now the only thing you have to do is that when the ChatActivity is created (`onCreate`), use the

[`getIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29) method of the activity and get the [extras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29).

Then check for the `UserId` and show the messages from the specified user.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding in here. I can clearly open the user chat screen with this method. But I can't handle such a condition:
If the chat screen of another user has already opened, I can't open a chatactivity for the new one. I always see the same chat activity which has already created.